# how to display anything multi line as it is on console screen/output in this case on command prompt using java //notepad

Tags: java, command-line, ascii, command-prompt

http://www.text-image.com/convert/ascii.html

I made ASCII character image From Text-Image.com of a dragon and I want to display that in command prompt with my java programme

I know how to create batch file// is their way to fire

https://youtu.be/ScQBQ0yYGfM

```
 String line = "Information \n " + 
               "More \n " + 
               "Even  stuff \n";

               System.out.println(line);
```

tried this but it is very painful to make every line matches the image

thanks in advance :)

dragon image in ASCII char/text on command prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this method:

```
private void printTxt(String image)
{
    /*
        image variable stores the path to the .txt file
        that contains the ASCII image.
    */
    try
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(image)));

        String line;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);

        }

        br.close();
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        //handle the exception
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx let me try I will come back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

result shows dragon yay!  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoYVG.png

did it using my own method 
something like this

```
   String line = "Information \n " + 
                 "More \n " + 
                 "Even  stuff \n";

                 System.out.println(line);
```

but thanx +THEvoid for your answer I dont know how to implement your soln I just started yesterday ;to learn java

I dont know how to assign path of txt file which contains ASCII img of dragon to image variable

Comment: If the txt file is in the same directory as your .java file(aka your source code) then the path is just the name of the file.For example "dragon.txt".